# add namespace string to all functions

Tags: c

In C, I want to add a namespace prefix string(without quotes) to all functions for which I want it to happen, and later on change the namespace string any time easily.

My approach:

```
#define NAMESPACE project_name

void NAMESPACE_func_name()
{
}

That should become:

void project_name_func_name()
{
}
```

Is that possible, how?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can't you achieve the same using IDE's find & replace? Just suggesting, though I understand the cons.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I'd never rely on my IDE. Some people don't use one as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with the macro concatenation operator and function-like macros:

```
#define NAMESPACE(name) project_name_ ## name

void NAMESPACE(func_name)(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the macro [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)

```
#define NAMESPACE(function) project_name ## function

void NAMESPACE(func_name)()
{
}
```